# Array subscript operator for pointer map

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dictionary, subscript

I have a struct with a std::map of pointers inside it. I'm trying to do the following:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo
{
    std::map<std::string, T*> f;
    T& operator[](std::string s)
    {
        return *f[s];
    }
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
Foo<Bar> f;
f["key"] = new Bar();
```

but the way it's written, it crashes the program. I also tried like this:

```
T* operator[](std::string s)
{
    return f[s];
}
```

but it doesnt compile. It says `"lvalue required as left operand of assignment"` on the `f["key"] = new Bar()` line.

I expected it to be easy since I'm trying to return a pointer and I'm storing a pointer. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way of doing this is:

```
T*& operator[](std::string s)
{
    return f[s];
}
```

and call it like `f["key"] = new Bar()`.

EDIT: You should start passing non-basic types by const reference where you can:

```
T*& operator[](const std::string& s)
```

Comment: Why `std::string s`? Why not `std::string const & s`?

Comment: Should have const and non-const methods for operator[]

Comment: Thanks for the help :D, but what does *& means and why use const references for parameters?

Comment: @LukeB. that's a pointer reference - an alias to the exact object returned by the method, not a copy of it. You pass by reference to prevent extra copy of the parameter.

Comment: It didn't work btw, this method still gives me a compile error in the assignment line, it says `cannot convert 'Bar*' to 'Bar**' in assignment|`.

Comment: @LukeB. are you using Foo<Bar> or Foo<Bar*> ?

Comment: Foo<Bar>, and adding the * in the map definition

Comment: Ah, I had a * in wrong place. Thanks for your time, it's working now :)